# Update FK column of the parent table with the PK of child table based on Where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
select t1.columnFK from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.columnFK=t1.columnpk AND t2.somecolumn='value1'



select t2.columnPK from table2 t2 where t2.somecolumn='value2'
```

So I have to update all the values from first select statement with the values of second one.
I tried writing update query like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.columnFK = table2.columnPK
From tabel1 t1, table2 t2
Where t1.columnfk=t2.columnpk AND somevalue='value2'
```

Here is the relationship
table2.columnpk is referenced as table1.coulmnfk.
table1.hbm.xml

```
<many-to-one
            name="table2"
            column="&quot;coulmnfk&quot;"
            class="table2class"
            cascade="none"/>
```

Table 2 relation goes like this:

```
<set name="table1" table="&quot;table1&quot;" inverse="true"  cascade="none">
                <key column="&quot;coulmnFK&quot;"/>
                <one-to-many class="table1"/>
            </set>
```

Not sure how would I include first condition.

Comment: In your first select you have written  where condition as  " where t1.columnFK=t1.columnpk " Which is wrong

Comment: Also are you getting any errors from your update statement? I think you would be getting error on your update statment because you just wrote somevalue = 'value2'. Instead you should use t2.somevalue = 'value2'. will you try

Comment: @Himanshu Yadav what sort of a relationship is this? :) You have a child pk as a fk in parent table? Don't you want to update child fk which refers to parent pk?

Comment: @AshReva The condition " where t1.columnFK=t1.columnpk " would be correct.  Foreign keys always reference (or should) the primary key of the other table.  Sometimes, the name of the primary key in the other table is used as the name of the field for the foreign key, but it's just a naming convention, not right or wrong.

Comment: I have added the relationship between the tables defined in the hbm file if this helps

Comment: @HimanshuYadav, you used somecolumn in the first code sample, but somevalue in the second code sample.  Other than that, I don't see how the first condition cannot simply be in the update.  What's the problem with " AND t2.somecolumn='value1' "?

Comment: @Marlin Pierce : But does table t1 has column "columnpk". To me it seems columnpk is from table "table2". Bit confused still. In his update statement he is joining correctly but in his first select statement it seemed wiered to me.

Comment: @AshReva I agree.  The question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stil find your referential integrity a bit odd to accept. Usually child table fk is updated with parent pk.

Here is the logic you may need to use, assuming you cureently have parent pk as a fk in your child talble and you are trying to add child pk as a fk into parent table...using a `join`

```
UPDATE parent
SET parent.childPK = child.PK    
FROM
    Parent
    JOIN
    child ON parent.PK = child.ParentPK
WHERE parent.somecolumn in ('value1','value2')
;
```

Comment: @Himansu please give this a try and comment, it's a bit a ambiguous to understand your query though, pardon me :)

Comment: Where parent.somecolumn doesn't exist. Somecolumn exist only in the child table which is referenced to parent table via foreign key.

Comment: Because in the question it didn't say table2 or table1 was parent key. So this was my best *blind* guess..to give you the logic. In that case you can change `WHERE child.somecolumn in (...)` and try.